# Excel development: How to detect that a Range overlaps another Range?

Tags: excel, interop, vsto

I am working on a VSTO Excel project and I am having some troubles managing Range objects.

Actually I have case where I need to know if the current selected range overlaps another Range that I stored in list. So basically, I have 2 Range instance and I want to compare their position.

This seemed simple pretty simple to me but with all the Interop dynamic stuff I am bit confused concerning which data I should rely on.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Application.Intersect` returns a range that is an intersection of the provided ranges, or `null` if they don't overlap.

Comment: Thank you. That was exactly what I was expecting and it does even more.